# 2-Way SSL Authentication SQL Server 2017 and Java application

Tags: authentication, ssl, mssql-jdbc

I have the task to configure SSL authentication for SQL Server running on docker container and Java application.

I have created the following mssqcl.conf file for the container from [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-security?view=sql-server-ver16). I'm using local trusted self-signed root certificate.

```
[network]
tlscert = /etc/ssl/certs/mssql.pem
tlskey = /etc/ssl/private/mssql.key
tlsprotocols = 1.2
forceencryption = 1
```

Following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-encrypted-connections?view=sql-server-ver16#client-initiated-encryption) it looks like there is "Server Initiated encryption" or "Client Initiated encryption" depending on the "forceenryption" flag and JDBC driver values "encrypt=false; trustServerCertificate=false;", however there is no information about 2-way SSL.

I don't find any useful information throughout the Microsoft SQL documentation at all just this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0495d743-a2dd-4ffc-8461-7038d8bae5d5/sql-server-mutual-authentication2way-ssl?forum=sqlsecurity) from 2020 saying that it is not possible for this moment.

So far I've monitored that there were successful handshakes (Server-side) in the logs and also I've validated that the connection is encrypted (the automation tests associated with the SSL passed) but I was wondering if 2-way SSL could be implemented and if yes how it could be validated?

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL Server 2022, SQL Server does not support 2-way SSL authentication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/authentication-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Azure SQL Databases do support certificate based authentication, but this is more of an Azure Active Directory extension then what you are seeking.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/certificate-based-authentication-for-azure-sql-database/ba-p/3109938